# Spring Ldap get roles/authorities from user

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-data, spring-ldap

i am trying to get the roles from a user in our ldap system.

First of all, my ldap user entry and role entry:

```
@Data
@Entry(objectClasses = {"inetOrgPerson", "top"}, base = "ou=people"
public class LdapUserEntry {

@Id
private Name id;

@DnAttribute(value = "uid")
private String username;

@Attribute(name = "cn")
private String cn;

@Attribute(name = "userPassword")
private String password;

@DnAttribute(value = "ou")
@Transient
private String group;


}
```

Role Entry class:

```
@Data
@Entry(objectClasses = {"groupOfUniqueNames", "top"}, base = "ourBase")
public class LdapRoleEntry {

@Id
private Name dn;

@DnAttribute("cn")
private String name;

@Attribute(name = "uniqueMember")
@Transient
private List<String> members;

}
```

For our authorization and authentication, i need to get the roles from the ldap, before the user gets logged.

EDIT: My Repos looks like:

```
public interface LdapUserRepository extends LdapRepository<LdapUserEntry> {

LdapUserEntry findByUsername(String username);

}
```

---

```
public interface LdapRoleRepository extends LdapRepository<LdapRoleEntry> {


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/tree/master/samples/user-admin/

Comment: thank you, i am trying to use it!

Comment: @xerx593 I am sorry, but i do not find the method, where can i put the username etc. to get the role of the searched user.

Can you comment it please?

Comment: to your particular question: check the `GroupRepo.findByMember()` and its usages. Unfortunately the sample is not working (outdated/version conflicts). [This](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-authenticating-ldap) has more recent activity (with spring-boot + spring-secutiry)